# AND with a mask is not giving accurate result

Tags: python

I have a string of binary value IR = '101010100011000000000011111111' and I am trying to get the left most 6 bits by performing AND with a mask

```
    >>> IR = '101010100011000000000011111111'
    >>> int(IR,base=2)
    713818367
    >>> 63<<26
    4227858432
    >>> bin(int(IR,base=2) & (63<<26))
    '0b101000000000000000000000000000'
```

But the output is supposed to be '0b101010000000000000000000000000'. 
The binary of both IR and the mask look good but once they are ANDed in their integer format, the value is changing. I have no idea why it is doing that. Does anyone know how to get the accurate result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you have is the accurate result. `63<<26` has more bits than `IR`, so `IR` is being left padded with 0s to perform `&`:

```
>>> len(bin(63<<26)) - 2
32
>>> len(bin(713818367)) - 2
30
```

You should do a left shift with 24 instead to get that result:

```
>>> 713818367 & 63<<24
704643072
>>> bin(_)
'0b101010000000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: yes, I did not notice that I lost two 0's at the beginning of IR. How can I not lose them?
        >>> IR = '00101010100011000000000011111111'
        >>> bin(int(IR,base=2) & (63<<26))
        '0b101000000000000000000000000000'

Comment: @SaiDuttal You didn't lose two zeros, and even if you did, it still would not make any difference

Comment: Got it. Thanks !